# Looking for suggestions on how to improve my Entity Relationship question

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, closed-questions, quality-improvement

I recently asked the following question:

[How can I display multi-valued attributes belonging to a multi-valued composite attribute in an ER diagram (relational database)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646579/how-to-display-multi-valued-attributes-belonging-to-a-multi-valued-composite-att)

However, it was closed as unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Therefore, I am looking for tips on how to improve that question—and my question-asking skills more generally.

I added problem cases, graphs, and yet somehow it's too broad or not descriptive enough, or the fact that I added extra body at the end of the description (with possible solution that I know works) or just adding a comment (... which just doesn't belong in the question but adds some extra unrelated info, like why I created a "imaginary" case with other names/variables because I can't disclose the real information).

I'm sorry if this question description is too broad, or you find it incomplete or not good enough. Just doing my best. I'm sorry if it contains typos and for all the grammar mistakes, English isn't my first language.

I have already read the commonly-linked resources, such as "how to ask questions", "what kinds of questions are allowed", etc.

On one of the comments other user said:

> You don't "ask 1 question" & you don't answer "Where are you stuck in what presentation of what information modelling & DB design method?". (And you don't describe the content of the ERD in text--what the diagram looks like.) As I told you, to answer 1 of the questions you ask is to (re)write a presentation of a method. A method you haven't identified. With no description of why you are stuck following it

I don't see how I'm asking multiple questions (there is only one) or how I should clarify more about the database. It's relational and I'm making an ER diagram, there is nothing more to it. The case is described in the text.

They claims I don't describe the content in text. While *the problem* is explained in threefold by now, once with entity/attribute terms, once in plain English, and once a summarized version. These 3 text portion describe exactly what the diagram looks like.

There is nothing to rewrite or rewriting I'm asking, plain and simple how to display the problem in an ER diagram for a relational database. We called it ER diagram for a relational database in all my lectures so really don't know how to specify this *even more*.

---

I've found an answer to the question on main site on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-display-multi-valued-attributes-belonging-to-a-multi-valued-composite-attribute-in-an-ER-diagram-relational-database).

Comment: In the question you linked, adding lots of **bold** words actually makes it quite difficult to read (in my opinion). I, personally, find all those bold characters quite distracting. Emphasis should be used minimally, **not** to **emphasise** any **keywords** in your **question**.

Comment: A word of advice: use a real word example, don't use labels "A", "B", "X", whatever. It makes it extremely hard to visualise what you're after, even with a diagram (which should be embedded in the question rather than being a link).

Comment: Side note as well, it's suggested to avoid words in all CAPITALS. In written text it comes across as you are shouting. If you really need to add emphasis to a word use **bold** or *italics* (but, like I mentioned in the first comment, use such emphases *sparingly*).

Comment: Everyone: thanks for all the edits/comments, they are like gold to me. @larnu I added all the bold to emphasize all the entities/attributes since I got comments that I should explain it in text rather than using a figure.

Comment: @Gimby I though using letters would be better, since it comes for a real world example but I couln't really share names. I changed it to fictive names now :) thanks for the tips everyone!

Comment: Yes, I left the emphasis on those, but removed it from things like the sentences in the middle of the question.

Comment: Or you could ignore that, and add huge lumps of text back into the question... Which is specifically what I said not to...

Comment: @larnu thanks for all the edits/tips. Yeah I realize it might seem a bit offensive, I'll resort to italic. I added all the bold later on in a rework, since I got asked to add text descriptions, while honestly I tried to describe the problem to the best of my ability and there wasn't much I could add ;)

Comment: @larnu srr I'll try to revert the change, you started editing the question while I was editing to, my apoligies....

Comment: @Conscius_Sibi fictive is fine, just as long as it is easy to visualise :) Animals tend to work well.

Comment: At least for me it would help if you would focus on *one* description of the task. Right now there seem to be three, and it's really hard to figure out whether they are all the same or if there are some additional details in each. It doesn't help that the "example figure if the text description above confuses you" does not relate to *any* terms used in any of the descriptions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for the advice! Yeah the two extra descriptions just followed after the comments from mister sphinxy who closed the question because it was too broad, had too little text,.... It's the 15th version (and the graph is still from the initial version). I let it be at this point, I'll ask a prof, takes less time :)

Comment: Your last edit only introduced what we call "meta noise". The reference should go as an edit on your SO question. Whether we "close" this question is decided by reviewers and they will do so without the need for guidance in the question.

Comment: "These 3 text portion describe exactly what the diagram looks like" But partly your question is, does the diagram agree with the text. So you contradict yourself--you know it does, but don't know whether it does. Anyway my request for a text version of the diagram (and, implicitly via the request for its method, a legend for it) has nothing to do with the rest of asking your question. You keep not doing as requested. You say many questions are 1 question. You say yours is the 1 method while I have said there are many--like your textbook says. You name it via comment not edit. Etc. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy I understand, the reviews are crucial for quality on stack overflow. I got sort of frustrated with it, so apologies if I came across as rude/mean.

Comment: You have only been respectful. PS The answers at the linked page are contradicted by your textbook. (Why don't you know that?) (Rhetorical.)

Comment: @philipxy let's agree to disagree on that last comment